# pandas dataframe update or set column[y] = x where column[z] = 'abc'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm new to python pandas and haven't found an answer to this in the documentation. I have an existing dataframe and I've added a new column Y. I want to set the value of column Y to 'abc' in all rows in which column Z = 'xyz'. In sql this would be a simple

```
update table set colY = 'abc' where colZ = 'xyz'
```

Is there a similar way to do this update in pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if you need set other `value` too:

```
df.loc[df.Z == 'xyz', 'Y'] = 'abc'
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3],
                   'Z':['xyz',5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   C  X    Z
0  7  1  xyz
1  8  2    5
2  9  3    6

df.loc[df.Z == 'xyz', 'Y'] = 'abc'

print (df)
   C  X    Z    Y
0  7  1  xyz  abc
1  8  2    5  NaN
2  9  3    6  NaN

df['Y1'] = np.where(df.Z == 'xyz', 'abc', 'klm')

print (df)
   C  X    Z    Y   Y1
0  7  1  xyz  abc  abc
1  8  2    5  NaN  klm
2  9  3    6  NaN  klm
```

You can use set column values too:

```
df['Y2'] = np.where(df.Z == 'xyz', 'abc', df.C)
print (df)
   C  X    Z    Y   Y2
0  7  1  xyz  abc  abc
1  8  2    5  NaN    8
2  9  3    6  NaN    9
```